# ASP.NET Core Web API - Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte' to 'EnumList.LeaveType?'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enums

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I am implementing Excel File upload using EPPLUS Excel Package.

I have this model:

```cs
public class LeaveApplication
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public LeaveType? LeaveType { get; set; }   
}
```

EnumList:

```cs
public class EnumList
{
    public enum LeaveType : byte
    {
        Annual = 1,
        Casual = 2,
        Compassionate = 3,
        Maternity = 4
    }
}
```

So I have this method for the Excel upload.

```cs
public async Task<List<LeaveApplication>> Import(IFormFile file)
{
    var list = new List<LeaveApplication>();
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
        {

            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
            var rowcount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
            var colcount = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;

            for (int row = 2; row < rowcount; row++)
            {
                list.Add(new LeaveApplication {
                    EmployeeId = worksheet.Cells[row,1].Value.ToString().Trim(),
                    StartDate = DateTime.Parse(worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value.ToString()),
                    EndDate = DateTime.Parse(worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value.ToString()),
                    LeaveType = byte.Parse(worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value.ToString())
                });
            }
        }
    }
    _dbContext.LeaveApplications.AddRange(list);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return list;
}
```

I got this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte' to 'EnumList.LeaveType?'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Then this line of code is highlighted:

```cs
LeaveType = byte.Parse(worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value.ToString())
```

How do I get this resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit cast from `byte` to `EnumList.LeaveType`.

```cs
LeaveType = String.IsNullOrEmpty(worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value.ToString())
    ? (EnumList.LeaveType?)null
    : (EnumList.LeaveType)byte.Parse(worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value.ToString())
```

Or you can work with parsing from `string` to `EnumList.LeaveType`:

```cs
LeaveType = String.IsNullOrEmpty(worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value.ToString())
    ? (EnumList.LeaveType?)null
    : Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumList.LeaveType), worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value.ToString())
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CfV9V3)

Will recommend using [`Enum.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?source=recommendations&view=net-7.0) to avoid the exception due to an invalid value for the `enum`.